# Tic tac toe computer choosing spot?

Tags: java

I have my tic tac toe game 90% finished, and had a form of computer AI, but that did not turn out too well. I am looking for a new easier source of generating a spot for the computer to move on the game board.

I need this computer move selection to pick a spot, but to also make sure that spot is freely available and there are no 'X's in that spot. Any ideas as to how to make the computer choose a spot?

```
/* I have 3 other methods drawing the board, and determining a tie, a loss, and a win not shown here for simplicity*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
             //Variable declaration
             Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
             char[][] Board = new char[3][3];
             String MenuInput;
             int BoardOutput;
             int UserSpotChoice;
             int ComputerSpotChoice = 0;
             int UserTurn = 0;
             int Winner = 0;
             Board[0][0] = '-';
             Board[0][1] = '-';
             Board[0][2] = '-';
             Board[1][0] = '-';
             Board[1][1] = '-';
             Board[1][2] = '-';
             Board[2][0] = '-';
             Board[2][1] = '-';
             Board[2][2] = '-';

             //Welcome
             System.out.println("Welcome to Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!");
             System.out.println("");
             System.out.println("If you wish to play, type 'Play'");
             System.out.println("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'");
             System.out.println("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'");
             MenuInput = kbReader.next();

             do {
                 if (MenuInput.equals("Play") || MenuInput.equals("play")) {
                     while (!GameOver) {
                         System.out.println("\f");
                         System.out.println(" Tic Tac Toe");
                         BoardOutput = DrawBoard(Board);
                         System.out.println(" 1 2 3");
                         System.out.println(" 4 5 6");
                         System.out.println(" 7 8 9");
                         System.out.println("Please enter the number you would like to move your spot to");
                         UserSpotChoice = kbReader.nextInt();

                         if (UserSpotChoice == 1) Board[0][0] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 2) Board[0][1] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 3) Board[0][2] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 4) Board[1][0] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 5) Board[1][1] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 6) Board[1][2] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 7) Board[2][0] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 8) Board[2][1] = 'X';
                         if (UserSpotChoice == 9) Board[2][2] = 'X';

                         do {
                             ComputerSpotChoice = (int)(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
                         }
                         while (Board[(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3][(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-'); //HERE IS THE OLD COMPUTER SPOT GENERATION THAT DID NOT WORK

                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 1) Board[0][0] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 2) Board[0][1] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 3) Board[0][2] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 4) Board[1][0] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 5) Board[1][1] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 6) Board[1][2] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 7) Board[2][0] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 8) Board[2][1] = 'O';
                         if (ComputerSpotChoice == 9) Board[2][2] = 'O';

                         Winner(Board);
                         Loser(Board);
                         Tie(Board);

                     } //While loop
                     //if (GameOver) System.exit (0) ;
                 } //If play
                 else if (MenuInput.equals("Instructions") || MenuInput.equals("instructions")) {
                     System.out.println("\f");
                     System.out.println("You will be playing the game of Tic Tac Toe against the computer.");
                     System.out.println("The object of this game is to get three of your own x's or o's in a line.");
                     System.out.println("You take turns placing the x's and o's and whoever gets three in a row first wins.");
                     System.out.println("Good Luck!");
                     System.out.println("");
                     System.out.println("If you wish to play, type 'Play'");
                     System.out.println("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'");
                     MenuInput = kbReader.next();
                 } else if (MenuInput.equals("Exit") || MenuInput.equals("exit")) {
                     System.out.println("Thank you for using Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!");
                     System.exit(0);
                 } else {
                     System.out.println("Sorry, that is not a valid choice.");
                     System.out.println("If you wish to play, type 'Play'");
                     System.out.println("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'");
                     System.out.println("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'");
                     MenuInput = kbReader.next();
                 }

             } //do while
             while (!MenuInput.equals("Instructions") || !MenuInput.equals("instructions") || !MenuInput.equals("Play") || !MenuInput.equals("play") || !MenuInput.equals("Exit") || !MenuInput.equals("exit"));
```

Comment: The optimal strategy for both players can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about game development and as such better fits to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: How is this different from the [other question you posted recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27539015/3097506)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method `public static boolean isSpotAvailable(int x, int y)`. Check after randomly finding a spot for pc, if it is available, use it, if not then choose a new spot.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach could be that, for every square you have, you check how many rows of 3 items you can create from that row. So for instance, the square in the middle would yield 4 (since you can create a horizontal row passing from the middle, a vertical row passing from the middle and two diagonals). On the other hand, squares at the edges would yield a value of 2 (since you can have 1 vertical and 1 horizontal).

If you want to have a more robust approach, then I think that the recommended way would be to use a [MiniMax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax). This will allow you to build a decision tree so that your algorithm *decides* where to place the next piece. An example of such an approach for tic tac toe can be found [here](http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the indices by using a HashSet object. As long as you can add a position between 1 to 9 into the set object successfully, the position is available. The other way is to use an ArrayDequeue object. Everytime a spot is used, the relevant spot index will be "removed" and if it is already out, the computer cannot use it.

```
/* For HashSet<Integer> object - Integer is an immutable wrapper class for int */

spotObj.add(spotLoc);  // Returns falls if the spot already exists i.e. used

/* For ArrayDequeue<Integer> object */ - Implementation of Queue interface */

spotObj.remove(spotLoc); returns false if it is already removed i.e. used
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to improve your AI by a lot.

**First:**  check the current state of the board and find all of the possible moves for the AI (which means: find all fields which are empty).

**Second:** find an opportunity to win this game which means you should simulate all of those possible moves from our first step and see if any of them lets you win the game.

-> if so: do that move!

-> if not: do a random move.

By doing this your AI would already be improved. But you can go even further by using a simple database. Keep track of all those moves your AI and the enemy does. 
Whenever you find yourself from now on in a situation where you would do a random move just check your database if you ever were in this situation before and how it turned out for you. According to the outcome of the former game in your database it might be a good idea to do the same move again or try out something different (by doing a random move).
Just append every game and its outcome to this database and you will see how your AI will get better from game to game.

If you need any code-examples just let me know.

Greetings Tim